# What's sirius.classes.Window and where can I get it?

Tags: java

I'm reconstructing a decompiled java program and currently I'm fixind dependencies. The last missing is `sirius.classes.Window`. I can't find it anywhere.

My attempt to [search it (with quotes)](https://www.google.cz/search?q=%22sirius.classes.Window%22) led to one result:

[image: Malwr - Malware Analysis by Cuckoo Sandbox]

That's analysis of the very file I have decompiled.

So what is it? It seems to provide some Windows API. Example usage:

```
//In property definition
Window window = new Window();
User32 user32 = window.getUser32();
Kernel32 kernel = window.getKernel32();
//More methods:
window.FindWindow("string");
window.isRunning("process name.exe");
window.getRect(hwndId);  //hwndId is also used in winapi, only as a handle instead of integer
//I'm not sure what the cid is
window.pixelCheck(cid, rgb, (int)x, (int)y, tolerance);
//The WinDef.RECT comes from com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef (https://github.com/twall/jna)
WinDef.RECT cRec = this.window.getRect(cid);
```

This class actually provides the most crucial features, so I can't omit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "Sirius - Open Source Test Automation Platform" - https://github.com/mkolisnyk/Sirius